# Can a plain style table view have sections?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

From the docs:

> A plain-style table view is an unbroken list; a grouped table view has visually distinct sections.

So in plain style, I can't have any sections? Or if I had some, they could not be visually distinct? Is that right?

Comment: why do you want to have section in plain style table view...? what is your exact requirement...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plain style table view can have sections, but they are divided only by a thin blue heading with the section name.  If you look at [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Art/types_of_table_views.jpg) image you can compare the different styles.  The left image is a plain table view without sections and the middle image is a plain view with sections.  The 'A' heading denotes a section called A.

Comment: link is not available now

Answer (score 2):

'Plain' can indeed have sections; the address book is a good example.

I'm not at my development machine, so can't grab a code example this minute. The mechanism to achieve this can differ depending on your method of providing data to your UITableView.

Will post examples later if no one else beats me to it.

EDIT: I can't add a comment to Matt's answer, so will add it here.
The thin blue line is the *default* implementation, you can provide your own custom views using the delegate:

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

Answer (score 2):

Yups, definitely they can have sections and the sections are separated by headers. For refernce please see the contacts application in iPhone device/simulator with some contacts added.

> ```
> A plain-style table view is an unbroken list; a grouped table view has visually distinct sections.
> ```

This line means in the grouped style table the sections are separated by some blank space but not in plain style tables

Answer (score 1):

**iOS UITableView styles(Plain, Grouped, Inset Grouped)**

> Can a plain style table view have sections?

Any tableview has sections

You are able to set style via `Attributes inspector` or via code `UITableView(frame: <CGRect>, style: <UITableView.Style>)` and can not be changed in runtime

Style defines a set of properties which setup some visual UI effects by default

**Plain**

doesn't have any setup

**Grouped**

- It has tableHeaderView and title of section header is collapsed to it
- Section has background from cell

**Inset Grouped**(from iOS v13, if you set via inspector for `< v13` - Grouped will be used )

- all from previous
- section with corner radius(10). It is not possible to change
- horizontal extra padding to cell(not for header). To change it use

```
self.tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 1, bottom:
   0, right: 1) //if set to 0 - no corners with radius
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , A plain tableview can have section
You need to  implement mmethods :
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView